# Add script inside script for Blogger credit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I designed some Blogger templates and I want to add credit as a script and not HTML, since my intention is to obfuscate it, so that people don't remove the credit to my shop.

The following HTML displays current year and Blogger blog's name:

```
<div style=""><script type='text/javascript'>var creditsyear = new Date();document.write(creditsyear.getFullYear());</script> &#169; <a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:blog.title/></a>. <a href='/'>Credit</a></div>
```

I need to make it work inside a function like this:

```
function credit(){var html="<a href='/' target='_blank'>Credit</a>";var containers=document.getElementsByClassName("content");var container=document.body;if(containers.length > 0)container=containers[containers.length-1];container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",html)};$(document).ready(credit);
```

How can I make it display Blogger blog's name and current year inside this script? Please, this is driving me crazy. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think this will be that what you're looking for:  
  
  
`function credit(){  
    var creditsyear = new Date(),
    fullYear = creditsyear.getFullYear(),
    html="<div>"+fullYear+" &#169; . <a href='/' target='_blank'>Credit</a></div>",
    containers=document.getElementsByClassName("content"),
    container=document.body;
    if(containers.length > 0)
        container=containers[containers.length-1];
    container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",html);
};

$(document).ready(credit);`

Comment: Thank you so much, Hiszpan! It worked adding the current year, however I can't add the Blogger blog title... I want it to show "2016 @ Blog Title. Designed by Blogger." This is the tag that should display it: <data:blog.title/> but doesn't work in the script.